# What does a disciplinary frame mean?

Tags: meaning

When writing an introduction, its important to orient readers in terms of disciplinary frame - what does this mean?

Comment: Is there something specific in it that you're having trouble with? A disciplinary frame will have its own set of definitions and rules which the reader might need in order to interpret the main body of the piece.

Comment: Probably [frame](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/frame#frame__14): *A basic structure that underlies or supports a system, concept, or text*. That is, "...important to orient readers in terms of the basic structure of the discipline being discussed."

Answer (score 2):

Different *disciplines* (areas of study or expertise) have different terminology and common assumptions. Because of that, a text within that discipline will be operating within a *frame* (structure in support of a system).

Readers from other disciplines, or lay-readers, may not be as familiar with such assumptions, and may use terminology differently. Indeed, it can often be that the case that people from relatively close disciplines use the same term in a subtly different way that can cause confusion.

Because of this, it's necessary to *orient* (provide a guide to position and direction) to the reader within that context.